# Primefaces: Is Drag and Drop logic using commandButton possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I am aware of the drag and drop feature in primefaces and now I want to be able to perform the logic of drag and drop on a commandButton click.

I have found JS codes to move up and down a datatable with defining moveUp and moveDown functions, however this is not what I am looking for.

Below is an example of what I want to be able to do.

E.g: I have a datatable and two commondButtons ("arrow up" and "arrow down"). When I click on "arrow up" the row should be moved one step (index) up and vice versa when I click on "arrow down".

I would really like to know, is such a method possible using JS ? If yes could you please provide me with the code example?

If you need anymore information please do let me know. Thanks in advance!

Update: This is what I currently have coded. This however doesn't work.

```
<script>
function move() {
    var table = $('#mytable').DataTable();

    var firstNode = table.row(rowIndex).node();

    function finalNode(){
        if (document.classList.contains('move up'))
            row(rowIndex - 1).node();
        else
            row(rowIndex + 1).node();
    }

    var LastNode = finalNode();
    
    simulateDragDrop(firstNode, lastNode);
}

function simulateDragDrop(sourceNode, destinationNode) {
    var EVENT_TYPES = {
        DRAG_END: 'dragend',
        DRAG_START: 'dragstart',
        DRAG_OVER: 'dragover',
        DROP: 'drop'
    }

    function createCustomEvent(type) {
        var event = new CustomEvent("CustomEvent")
        event.initCustomEvent(type, true, true, null)
        event.dataTransfer = {
            data: {
            },
            setData: function(type, val) {
                this.data[type] = val
            },
            getData: function(type) {
                return this.data[type]
            }
        }
        return event
    }

    function dispatchEvent(node, type, event) {
        if (node.dispatchEvent) {
            return node.dispatchEvent(event)
        }
        if (node.fireEvent) {
            return node.fireEvent("on" + type, event)
        }
    }

    var event = createCustomEvent(EVENT_TYPES.DRAG_START)
    dispatchEvent(sourceNode, EVENT_TYPES.DRAG_START, event)

    var dropEvent = createCustomEvent(EVENT_TYPES.DROP)
    dropEvent.dataTransfer = event.dataTransfer
    dispatchEvent(destinationNode, EVENT_TYPES.DROP, dropEvent)

    var dragOver = createCustomEvent(EVENT_TYPES.DRAG_OVER)
    dragOver.dataTransfer = event.dataTransfer
    dispatchEvent(destinationNode, EVENT_TYPES.DRAG_OVER, dragOver)
    
    var dragEndEvent = createCustomEvent(EVENT_TYPES.DRAG_END)
    dragEndEvent.dataTransfer = event.dataTransfer
    dispatchEvent(sourceNode, EVENT_TYPES.DRAG_END, dragEndEvent)
}
</script>
```

Comment: Something like [this](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-v8/ui/data/datatable/reorder.xhtml)? Or do you want to convert the drag & drop feature into two buttons?

Comment: @WoAiNii I want to convert the drag & drop feature into two buttons.

Comment: Have you tried doing it server side? For example, with two methods that receive current row, and changes  in the array its position, updating at the end the dataTable.

Comment: @WoAiNii yes, this however is causing some sorting issues and so my last resort is using javascript. :(

Comment: Is your table with lazy loading? With sorting/filtering? Pf version?